# Automatic unique color for files of the same project

Tags: atom-editor

I was trying to search a package that would let me differentiate my projects **giving their opened files a unique color, based on each project**.

Sometimes I have two or three files named equal, for example "a.xxx" from three different projects and It would be nice that, when opened, a different color was assigned to each "a.xxx". One unique color for each project.

I tried to find such package but only found some that changed the background color of the project and others that manually assign colors to tabs.

Do you know some module that does that automatically?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if this helpful or not :

> i am using "[Smart Tab Name](https://atom.io/packages/smart-tab-name)" to different the file name and
>   "[color tab](https://atom.io/packages/color-tabs)" to color it manually

I know a Plugin that might work :

> that search the name with regex and color it => "[color-tabs-regex](https://atom.io/packages/color-tabs-regex)"
>   
>  but in my case there still issue with the usage manual.